# How to get bounding rectangle of a set of point?

Tags: opencv, graphics, point, bounding-box

I want to get bounding rectangle of a set of points. The bounding rectangle must fit most of these points.
When I use `cv2.minAreaRect` ,I can only get rectangle that has min area.As shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXX0S.jpg)

But the rectangle I want to get is shown by the red rectangle in the figure below, which can fit the points
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zasul.jpg)

how can I get such rectangle?
is there some fitting function can fit points to rectangle?

I really need some help,thank you!

Comment: Please add your original input image without the drawn boxes

Comment: Your problem is relatively ill defined and I doubt that there is a general solution for that. However, it might be easier to suggest something once we understood what you are actually trying to do. What makes the red rectangle superior to the minArea rectangle? What are you going to do with th result?